# Why won't this bytecode verify

Tags: java, debugging, bytecode, verify

EDIT: The solution is that I was using aastore, when I should have been using iastore, because I wanted to store an item in an array of *ints*, while aastore is only for arrays of *Objects*.

I have the following method I'm generating as a constructor in bytecode

```
aload_0
invokespecial java/lang/Object/<init>()V
aload_0
new java/lang/StringBuilder
dup
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>()V
putfield com/js/interpreter/custom_types/1e9ebd0/s Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_0
iconst_0
putfield com/js/interpreter/custom_types/1e9ebd0/l I
aload_0
iconst_0
multianewarray [I 1
astore_1
iconst_0
istore_2
goto 23
18:aload_1
iload_2
iconst_0
aastore
iinc 2 1
23:iload_2
iconst_0
if_icmplt 18
aload_1
putfield com/js/interpreter/custom_types/1e9ebd0/a [I
return
```

However, it fails to verify, giving method:  signature: ()V) Expecting to find object/array on stack

However, I can go through and know precisely the number of items on the stack at all times:

```
    aload_0
1
    invokespecial java/lang/Object/<init>()V
0
    aload_0
1
    new java/lang/StringBuilder
2
    dup
3
    invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>()V
2
    putfield com/js/interpreter/custom_types/1e9ebd0/s Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
0
    aload_0
1
    iconst_0
2
    putfield com/js/interpreter/custom_types/1e9ebd0/l I
0
    aload_0
1
    iconst_0
2
    multianewarray [I 1
2
    astore_1
1
    iconst_0
2
    istore_2
1
    goto 23
    18:aload_1
2
    iload_2
3
    iconst_0
4
    aastore
1
    iinc 2 1
1
    23:iload_2
2
    iconst_0
3
    if_icmplt 18
1
    aload_1
2
    putfield com/js/interpreter/custom_types/1e9ebd0/a [I
0
    return
```

When I run it through the Justice verifier, it doesn't give me any useful messages (and it even fails to verify classes generated by javac).

What could be going on here?  What's the problem?

Comment: not that this is pertainent, but why are you using `multianewarray [I 1` instead of `anewarray`?

Comment: It's easier to generate multianewarray instructions generically.  I'm planning on optimizing stuff like that later.

Comment: I guess the "Expecting to find object/array on stack", means you have the wrong type of argument on the stack somewhere.... an int instead of a reference? Maybe you should extend your stack element count, with the types on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem, but here's what I do when I get sucked into the bytecode-debugging hell:

- Omit unnecessary code. currently it seems that the loop is a nop (you never enter into the body loop because you initialize local variable 2 with zero, right?). So I would just make the body of the loop be empty and see if the verification bug persists.
- Then, I will start removing other pieces (the initialization of the various fields), until the bug disappears.

Comment: The problem is that I'm testing a code generator.  I don't want to just optimize it away, because then it will fail intermittently when it can't be optimized.  I mean, if I remove the loop, it verifies fine.  But I need it to work when the loop *isn't* removable.  I can't split the loop up into smaller pieces, because otherwise it would leave the stack inconsistent, so I can't divide and conquer any further.

Comment: Using a little more smarts(replacing operands with pop instructions), I managed to figure out that it was because I was using an aastore instruction instead of an iastore instruction on an array of ints.

Comment: I am saying that by gradually removing pieces of the generated code you can zero in on the piece that causing the verification problem. So you now know the problem is due to the loop. Start removing individual pieces of the loop until you find the one that is broken.

Comment: Just saw your second comment. So, I guess you figured out what I meant. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps i'm confused but you do

```
1
jsr 23

...

23: iload_2
2
```

but after 23, i'd think there'd be 3 on the stack

```
A0
<return address>
I2
```

Comment: Thanks, You're right, I was confused.  I was looking for goto, not jsr.  However, I still get the same verification error with the fix.